# I cannot create the luac.cross compiler. How can I fix "undefined reference to 'strtol'"?

Tags: lua, nodemcu

My goal is to be able to cross-compile Lua code for my ESP8266 before uploading to the device.
 The official documentation is [here](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/upload/#compiling-lua-on-your-pc-for-uploading).

I have the same issue as [this person](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=60249). At first I also had a "missing c_limits.h" error and solved it due to that post. However, unlike the original poster, I am experiencing the "strtol" error on both master and dev branches and have been unable to find a solution myself.

The error message is **"undefined reference to `c_strtol'"** in lobject.c, in the 'lua0_strtod' function.

strtol is defined in stdlib.h, which is in the same include folder as limits.h, so I am unclear why the definition cannot be found. I have done some hunting through the source code to see if the appropriate headers were not included in a source file but I have been unsuccessful in finding the problem.

Edit:
The exact command that produces the error is (running from the root directory of the source code):

```
lua tools/cross.lua
```

I have always run this after successfully running

```
make
```

Comment: Can you please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Or show at least all the exact compilation commands.